# Correct Way to Wrap a Hibernate PersistentSet in a Custom Implementation?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have implemented an `ObservableSet` class that wraps a Set and implements the Set interface and the Observable pattern, firing events to registered listeners when elements are added or removed. I'd like to use this ObservableSet in a class that Hibernate maps.  Hibernate wants getters and setters for `Set`, and sets them to be instances of `PersistentSet.` As in [this question from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280771/converting-hibernates-persistentset-into-copyonwritearrayset), I initially tried adding logic to the Getter and Setter to wrap whatever Set was passed in with an ObservableSet, but this results in the exception: `Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: ...`

I don't need to listen for changes from within Hibernate. My main concern is that once I deserialize the object from the database, I can listen to changes. I could write a second (non-beans) getter that just returns the wrapper ObservableSet, and then enforce through coding convention that we don't alter the contents of the inner set except through the wrapper we get through this method, but that seems kind of unpleasant and hacky.

Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you need to fire events to listeners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate a One-To-Many collection with an annotation as follows:

```
@OneToMany(...)
@CollectionType(type = "some.collection.Type")
public Set<Entity> getEntities() {
    return entities;
}
```

And implement some.collection.Type such that it wraps the PersistentSet:

```
public class TestCollectionType implements UserCollectionType {
    @Override
    public PersistentCollection instantiate(SessionImplementor session, CollectionPersister persister)
                    throws HibernateException {
            return new Wrapper(new PersistentSet(session));
    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiate(int anticipatedSize) {
            return new Wrapper(new HashSet<>());
    }

    @Override
    public PersistentCollection wrap(SessionImplementor session, Object collection) {
            return new Wrapper(new PersistentSet(session, (Set<?>)collection));
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator getElementsIterator(Object collection) {
            return ((Set<?>)collection).iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object collection, Object entity) {
            return ((Set<?>)collection).contains(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public Object indexOf(Object collection, Object entity) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Object replaceElements(Object original, Object target, CollectionPersister persister, Object owner,
                    Map copyCache, SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException {
            ((Set<?>)target).clear();
            ((Set<?>)target).addAll((Set)original);
            return target;
    }
}
```

List or Map is implemented the same way.